# Autopep8 = Insert whitespace automatically around the "=" in a keyword argument?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I want to automatically insert white space around '=' in a keyword argument,

eg. through a config option in `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [......]` in `settings.json`.

The goal is to automatically fix the `E225:missing whitespace around operator`.

For example, I want to transform `Users.objects.get(id=userId)` to `Users.objects.get(id = userId)`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Anyways, I doubt autopep8 will have a config option for that, because [it breaks PEP8 recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

Comment: What linter is giving the "E225:missing whitespace around operator"? (flake8?) What's its version?

Comment: It just doesn't seem to add spaces to the brackets from around the equals sign. Without parentheses, formatting the document would add spaces around the equal sign.